# Multiple pages CSS - Different styles in each page for same elements

Tags: css

I want the elements on 1 page to be styled and not affect the same elements on another page.

I have `class="homepage"` on each element.

Is there a better way to do it?

For simplicity, here is the DIV on that page.

```css
h1.homepage, p.homepage, li.homepage {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
p.homepage, li.homepage {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1 class="homepage">Angular 2 with TypeScript for Beginners</h1>
    <br> 
    <p class="homepage">This project teaches what single page applications (SPA) are and how to build them.</p>
    <p class="homepage">This is a real-world application. A Single Page Application with 2 pages.</p>
    <ul class="homepage">
        <li class="homepage">Page 1 - is a list of customers from a RESTful api with CRUD operations.</li>
        <li class="homepage">Page 2 - is a list of posts from a RESTful api with pagination and search opeartions as well as master/detail views</li>
    </ul>
    <br>      
    <p class="homepage">Angular 2 is the next big thing. It's one of the leading frameworks for building modern, scalable, cross-platform apps.</p>
    <p class="homepage">It’s a leading framework for building JavaScript heavy applications. Often is used in building Single Page Applications (SPA). In a standard web app, when we click on a link, the entire page is reloaded. In SPA, instead of reloading the entire page, we replace the view that is in the content area with another view. It also keeps track of history so if the user navigates using back and forward buttons, we reinsert the application in the right state. This is a fast and fluid experience. Gmail is an example of a SPA.</p>      
    <br>  
    <p class="homepage">TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, meaning any valid JavaScript code is valid TypeScript. TypeScript brings many useful features to JavaScript that are missing in the current version of JavaScript. We get classes, modules, interfaces, properties, constructors, access modifiers (e.g. public/private), IntelliSense and compile-time checking. So, we can catch many programming errors at compile-time.
    </p>
    <p class="homepage">Angular 2 is written in TypeScript. Plus, most of their documentation is in TypeScript. And for that reason, TypeScript will be the dominant language in building Angular 2 apps.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What about just creating a "homepage.css" file and linking it only to the homepage? Then link the "design.css" file for all the other pages. You can even have both on the homepage, just put the "homepage.css" file after the "design.css" file so it overrides the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better alternative.

Surround the page with a class and use descendant selectors:

```css
.homepage h1, .homepage p, .homepage li
{
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.homepage p, .homepage li
{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
    <h1>Angular 2 with TypeScript for Beginners</h1>
    <br> 
    <p>This project teaches what single page applications (SPA) are and how to build them.</p>
    <p>This is a real-world application. A Single Page Application with 2 pages.</p>
    <ul >
        <li>Page 1 - is a list of customers from a RESTful api with CRUD operations.</li>
        <li>Page 2 - is a list of posts from a RESTful api with pagination and search opeartions as well as master/detail views</li>
    </ul>
    <br>      
    <p>Angular 2 is the next big thing. It's one of the leading frameworks for building modern, scalable, cross-platform apps.</p>
    <p>It’s a leading framework for building JavaScript heavy applications. Often is used in building Single Page Applications (SPA). In a standard web app, when we click on a link, the entire page is reloaded. In SPA, instead of reloading the entire page, we replace the view that is in the content area with another view. It also keeps track of history so if the user navigates using back and forward buttons, we reinsert the application in the right state. This is a fast and fluid experience. Gmail is an example of a SPA.</p>      
    <br>  
    <p>TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, meaning any valid JavaScript code is valid TypeScript. TypeScript brings many useful features to JavaScript that are missing in the current version of JavaScript. We get classes, modules, interfaces, properties, constructors, access modifiers (e.g. public/private), IntelliSense and compile-time checking. So, we can catch many programming errors at compile-time.
    </p>
    <p>Angular 2 is written in TypeScript. Plus, most of their documentation is in TypeScript. And for that reason, TypeScript will be the dominant language in building Angular 2 apps.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks..I had initially had the <div class="homepage"> and had the style as  .homepage h1, p, li    Which was messing things up.

Answer (score 1):

What keeps you from using different stylesheets (e.g. `general.css` for every other page and `homepage.css` for this particular one) in the first place?
If you don't want to bother with multiple css files, you could declare the class solely to your `div` and still use it for the distinction in your css.
Just as an example:

```
<style>
   span {
      background-color: red;
  }

  div.homepage span {
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <span>span in normal div</span>
</div>
<div class="homepage">
  <span>span in special div</span>
</div>
```